# Django - html submit to view to api call to html page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

So I am as Green as they come and am attempting the following. Our Work Management app has an average API but a very poor customer portal. I am attempting to produce at least a prototype of what I want and have been using Django (for the first time) I think I am almost there but have got myself all tangled. Being a newbie the Documentation does not enlighten me much.

From one of the web pages the user enters a job number and clicks submit. I need that job number to complete my API call then I want to display the job information in job.html
After a few days (like 5)

I have the job number passing to the view and see the JSON data in the terminal but cannot get it to display in job.html

I am getting this error

`AttributeError at /job/ 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers' Request Method: POST Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/job/ Django Version: 3.2.dev20210111104520 Exception Type: AttributeError Exception Value:     **'dict' object has no attribute 'headers'** Exception Location: c:\users\davidp\django\django\middleware\clickjacking.py, line 33, in process_response Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe **Python Version:   3.8.2**`

I had the job page working when I manually entered a job number to the code but that was a few days ago and it my attempts to get everything else working I seem to have destroyed that part.

base.html - User adds job number and hits Submit

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"  method ='POST'action="/job/">{% csrf_token %}
      <input  type="text" placeholder="Job Number"name="job2find">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" target='job' type="submit">Find Job</button>
    </form>
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import include, path 
from django.conf.urls import url


from display_faults import views
from display_faults.views import GetFaults, GetJobs, GetInvoices, GetJ
from display_faults.views import get_Job

urlpatterns = [
   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('faults/', GetFaults.as_view(template_name='faults.html'), name='tt_tickets'),
    path('invoices/', GetInvoices.as_view(template_name='invoices.html'), name='tt_tickets'),
    path('todayjb/',views.Showjb,name='Enable_Jobs'),
    path('job/',views.get_Job)
    #path('job/', GetJ.as_view(template_name='job.html'))
]
```

views.py

```
def get_Job(request,*args, **kwargs):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method=="POST":
        print('*'*50)
       
        jb= request.POST['job2find']
        print (jb)
        print('*'*50) 
        jobber=jb
       

        url = ("https://middle of my url/jobs/"+jobber)
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization':'Bearer %s' % 'bearer is here but will be moved'})
        jobs = r.json()
        job_list = []
        print (jobs)
    
    return jobs
```

job.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<body>

<p>
  

Job ID:
  <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="{{jobs.ID}}">
Name:
<input type="text" name="textfield5" id="textfield5"value="{{jobs.Name}}">
Stage:
  <input type="text" name="textfield6" id="textfield6"value="{{jobs.Stage}}">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
Order:
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"value="{{jobs.OrderNo}}">
  
  Status:
<input type="text" name="textfield7" id="textfield7"value="{{jobs.Status.Name}}">
Due Date:
  <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3"value="{{jobs.DueDate}}">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
Site Address:
  <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4"value="{{jobs.Site.Name}}"size="80" >
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
  <label for="textarea6">Notes:</label>
  <textarea name="textarea2"rows="10" cols="150" id="textarea6">{{jobs.Notes}}</textarea>
</p>
<label>Description:</label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
{{jobs.Description|safe}}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> 
    {%endblock%}
   
    
  

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks and I apologise if I have butchered the code.

Comment: minus some other issues, I'd try using a JsonResponse in your get_Job function. `return JsonReponse(jobs)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects But you'll get errors if that isn't a post request. You'll also need to import JsonResponse: `from django.http import JsonResponse`